# How to clear float only in curent div?

Tags: html, css

I have the followin g HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-block">
        <p>
            some text
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-block">
        <p>
           some text
        </p>
        <div class="some-block">654</div>
        <div class="some-block">132</div>
        <div class="some-block">987</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="regular-block">10002</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

blocks with class `left-block` and `some-block` have property `float:left`
This looks like http://jsfiddle.net/5k5v67jj/
block with class `clear` has `clear:left;`

How can I make block `regular-block` to like on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please include your CSS in your question as well. I'm also not entirely sure what you're asking when you say, "to like on this screenshot."

Comment: @MattD to clarify the OP means the box with `100002` is expecte tobe under the yellow boxes.... but i'ts clearing the float of the left box also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to contain the float and the clear in a [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting). To set up such a context, a common practice is to use `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden`. You'd add this to the styling of the div  with the "right-block" class.

See http://jsfiddle.net/5k5v67jj/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. In my project adding `overflow:auto` was enough. )))

Answer (score 0):

I would change `.some-block` from `float:left;` to `display:inline;`. That way, a standard div like `.regular-block` will automatically show underneath and you don't need a clear between them.

Then you can put the `clear` div at the bottom to fix the block heights:

```css
.wrapper{
    border: 1px solid brown;
}
.left-block{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.right-block{
    margin-left: 112px;
    border: 1px solid green;    
    padding:5px;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
.some-block{
    display:inline;
    border: 1px solid yellow;  
}
.regular-block{
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid violet;  
}
.clear{
    clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-block">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tristique, lorem dapibus tristique rhoncus, justo erat volutpat erat, in malesuada enim libero quis metus. Nunc tristique maximus efficitur. Sed nec dolor ut quam consequat molestie id quis justo. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-block">
        <p>
            Nunc a lectus enim. Quisque sit amet iaculis turpis, a auctor tortor. Mauris aliquet sapien non odio tempor, auctor gravida nunc commodo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum eu tellus vel volutpat. Cras sed neque egestas, ullamcorper purus id, viverra odio. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce et malesuada est, et bibendum lectus. 
        </p>
        <div class="some-block">654</div>
        <div class="some-block">132</div>
        <div class="some-block">987</div>
        <div class="regular-block">10002</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: In my project there are a lot of pages where I can not apply `display:inline` property. Is there any way to clear floating only in current block?

Comment: The problem isn't the floating of the `regular-block`, it is the clearing of `clear`. As soon as you do that, everything will be underneath the left panel